# Duplicate instances within Gnome menu

Tags: gnome3

I'm running Fedora 18 with Gnome 3.6.

I've installed Eclipse manually, and added the menu entry with alacarte. My problem is that even though I have "Favorite"'d the menu entry, it keeps duplicating the entry every time a new instance is launched. See screenshot for example:

[image]

Normally, it would group the new instances under one icon. For some reason my menu entry just won't match up. I have tried to rename the menu entry to what the application's title is when starting up but to no avail. I'm not quite sure what is causing this behavior, but would really love some assistance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [don_crissti suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74405/duplicate-instances-within-gnome-menu#comment108264_74405), I was missing the WMCLASS key within my .desktop entry. Without this, the DM(here beign Gnome3.6) failed to match the windows together with the specified menu entry.
The launcher now groups all subsequent instances of Eclipse together now.

From what I've read about the .desktop file specification, [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/startup-notification-spec/startup-notification-0.1.txt), is that the optionally extra key specified during the launching process provides an identifier to match other associated top-level(parent?) windows with:

> **WMCLASS**
>
> ```
>       a string to match against the "resource name" or "resource
>       class" hints. If this key is present, the launchee will most
>       likely not send a "remove" message on its own. If the
>       desktop environment detects a toplevel window mapped with
>       this name or class, it should send a "remove" message for 
>       the startup sequence.
> ```

And further on within the document:

> **StartupWMClass=STRING**
>
> If true, it is KNOWN that the application will map at least one
>     window with the given string as its WM class or WM name hint.

Comment: You can get the WMCLASS(es) of any window by running the following command in terminal: `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` and clicking on the window the class of which you are interested in.